# JPA onetoMany/ManytoOne persist - integrity constraint violated - parent key not found

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My mapping files (relevant data):

Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "NAME_TEXT"))
@SequenceGenerator(name="ATTRIBUTE_NAME_SEQ",    sequenceName="ATTRIBUTE_NAME_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class AttributeNameVo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,    generator="ATTRIBUTE_NAME_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 6, scale = 0)
    private int attributeId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "attributeNameVo")
    private Set<AttributeFunctionalUsageVo> attributeFunctionalUsageVos = new HashSet<AttributeFunctionalUsageVo>(0);
```

Child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTRIBUTE_FUNCTIONAL_USAGE")
public class AttributeFunctionalUsageVo implements Serializable {

        @EmbeddedId
        @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "attributeId", column = @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_ID", nullable = false, precision = 6, scale = 0) ),
                             @AttributeOverride(name = "functionalAreaCd", column = @Column(name = "FUNCTIONAL_AREA_CD", nullable = false, length = 5) ) })
        private AttributeFunctionalUsageIdVo id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "attributeId", referencedColumnName="ATTRIBUTE_ID", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private AttributeNameVo attributeNameVo;
```

Then I do in code (pseudo-code):

```
  AttributeNameVo attr = new AttributeNameVo();
  AttributeFunctionalUsageVo attrFunc = new AttributeFunctionalUsageVo();
  attr.getAttributeFunctionalUsageVos().add(attrFunc);
  attrFunc.setAttributeNameVo(attr);
```

In the DAO:

```
  em().persist(attr);
```

The log result shows:

```
select ATTRIBUTE_NAME_SEQ.nextval from dual

insert into ATTRIBUTE_NAME (ACTIVE_FL, DATE_CREATED, DATE_MODIFIED,  DISPLAY_SEQ_NO, EXTERNAL_REF_ID, HINT_TEXT, LOV_FL, MAX_LENGTH, MAX_RANGE, MIN_RANGE, NAME_TEXT, POS_FL, PUBLIC_FL, RAPID_SEARCH_FL, REQUIRED_FL, TYPE_CD, USER_CREATED, USER_MODIFIED, ATTRIBUTE_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

insert into ATTRIBUTE_FUNCTIONAL_USAGE (DATE_CHANGED, DATE_CREATED, DATE_MODIFIED, USER_CREATED, USER_MODIFIED, ATTRIBUTE_ID, FUNCTIONAL_AREA_CD) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And then the error:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ATTR_FUNCTIONAL_USAGE_ATTRB_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

Would appreciate help in fixing this issue. I have tried many things, but yet nothing ...

Based on the question in the comment the entity mapping for embeddable id is:

```
public class AttributeFunctionalUsageIdVo implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_ID", nullable = false, precision = 6, scale = 0)
private int attributeId;
```

Comment: How is EmbeddedId class defined? Please provide it for better understanding the relational model. Does AttributeFunctionalUsageIdVo.id.attributeId field in `AttributeFunctionalUsageVo` entity correspond to primary key of `AttributeNameVo` entity?

Comment: I provided the AttributeFunctionalUsageIdVo class in the above edit.

Yes, it does correspond the to the primary key in the AttributeFunctionalUsageVo table

Comment: Just to clarify inconsistencies: 1) There is no `AttributeListValueAllIdVo` in the entities - should it be `AttributeFunctionalUsageIdVo` instead?  2) Pseudo-code persists `AttributeVo` - should it be `AttributeNameVo` instead?

Comment: _it does correspond the to the primary key in the AttributeFunctionalUsageVo table_ - to be more specific: Does `attributeId` in embeddable correspond (is the same as) to `attributeId` in your parent entity?

Comment: @wypieprz - I corrected the embedded id class. Also, yes the attributeId is the same in the embeddable id and parent entity.

Comment: Your join column specifies a "attributeId" database field is the foreign key, while the attribute override states it is overriding a "attributeId"  property to use a "ATTRIBUTE_ID" database field.  It seems like you intend both to be using "ATTRIBUTE_ID" in the database as the ID and foreign key.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, that is right. Unfortunately that's the table structure and relation. Not ideal but currently unavoidable :(

Comment: I don't understand.  Is the foreign key  "attributeId" or is it "ATTRIBUTE_ID"?  I believe you need to change your join column to use "ATTRIBUTE_ID" instead of the "attributeId" you have specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is required because you have made the attributeNameVo mapping within AttributeFunctionalUsageVo as read only (insertable = false, updatable = false), so JPA is required to check the other mapping for the 'attributeId' field within your embeddable ID to set its value.  If you don't update that field manually with a value, it is null when the insert happens, and is why you get the failure.

There are a number of options depending on which JPA version you are working with.  If you must use JPA 1.0, you can modify your mappings so that attributeNameVo is writable and the mapping in the embeddable has is read only, (switch the  insertable, updatable settings on the two mappings).  JPA will then pull the 'attributeId' field from the relationship, ignoring any changes to the embeddedid id field.  This will result in it being null unless you refresh or otherwise reload the entity from the database though.

JPA 2.0 introduced other options, such as allowing relationships to be marked as the ID, or even stating that the join field [maps to the Id](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) field.  You would then use:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("attributeId")
private AttributeNameVo attributeNameVo;
```

Where the "attributeId" is the name of the mapping within the Embedded ID.  JPA will then set the attributeId value in the embeddedID with the primary key of the AttributeNameVo for you, as well as handle the inserts correctly.

Comment: First thing I tried already was setting (insertable=true, updatable=false) . However, hibernate doesn't seem to like that and server fails to start up

I am infact using JPA 2.0. I will try '@MapsId' solution and report back by next week.

Comment: You have 2 mappings to the field.  You should have one of them with both insertable and updatable set to true, while the other marked as false.  MapsId is the better option, but you should still find out why your server won't start up if you've set up the mapping correctly.

Comment: I tried using @MapsId. Persist works just fine and retrieves the generated id and propagtes to the child entity. However, on commit I get the error: `ORA-00972: identifier is too long` the insert statement shows as : `insert into ATTRIBUTE_FUNCTIONAL_USAGE (DATE_CHANGED, DATE_CREATED, DATE_MODIFIED, USER_CREATED, USER_MODIFIED, **id_attributenamevo_ATTRIBUTE_ID**, FUNCTIONAL_AREA_CD) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Any help ??

Comment: OK FINALLY!!! got it working .. I guess I still needed to have `@JOIN_COLUMN` annotation alongwith `@MapsId`. I will mark as accepted your answer. Thanks !!

Comment: "id_attributenamevo_ATTRIBUTE_ID" is the default join column as defined by the JPA specification when the join column isn't there.  Glad it is working

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for TEMP purposes I have solved this by doing a persist and then flush to get the parent records with the "id". Then I loop through the child objects in the "persisted" record and "set" it's corresponding FK manually.

Again, not a perfect solution and inefficient but it seems to have done the trick ... I would still appreciate if anyone can suggest a more elegant and better solution. If I see something better, I will accept that answer!