# Not able to save data using OneToOne mapping

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to save data in two table using `OneToOne` mapping.I have followed
[this](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-using-annotations-1.html),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814809/jpa-onetomany-manytoone-persist-integrity-constraint-violated-parent-key-not),[this](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/),[this](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-one-foreignkey-relationship-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/) and few more online resources to accomplish this, but it is throwing

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TableName.TEST_ID) violated - parent key not found
```

Creating a table where column `TESTID` is foreign key. In the parent table `TESTID` is primary key.That primary key is generated using sequence generator

```
CREATE TABLE EW_TEST_REFTABLE (
  ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  TESTNAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  TESTID int,
  CONSTRAINT test_id FOREIGN KEY(TESTID)
  REFERENCES EW_TESTDATA(TESTID)
);
```

Ew_testdataEntity.java (Entity class of parent table)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EW_TESTDATA")
public class Ew_testdata {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sube_seq",
            sequenceName = "EW_TESTDATA_SEQ",
            allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sube_seq")

    @Column(name = "TESTID")
    private int testid;

    @Column(name = "TESTNAME")
    private String testname;

    // Ew_test_reftable  is another entity class.In that table the column
    // TESTID (foreign key) must be same as the primary key of this 
    // entity/table(EW_TESTDATA)
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TESTID",unique = true)
    private Ew_test_reftable ewtestreftable;

       //Constructor
       // getter & setter
    }
```

Ew_test_reftable.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EW_TEST_REFTABLE")
public class Ew_test_reftable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "subf_seq", sequenceName = "EW_REF_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "subf_seq")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TESTNAME")
    private String testname;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "TESTID")
    private int testid;
    //Constructor,getter & setter
}
```

Service to save data using `Jpa`

```
@Override
    public Ew_testdata ew_testdata(String name) {

        Ew_test_reftable ew_test_reftable = new Ew_test_reftable();
        ew_test_reftable.setTestname("test");
        Ew_testdata ew_testdata = new Ew_testdata();
        ew_testdata.setTestname(name);
        ew_testdata.setEwtestreftable(ew_test_reftable);
        iew_tEst.ewTestdata(ew_testdata);
        return null;
    }
```

The problem seems to be similar to few other problem described in SO but still i am not able to figure out where I am making mistake

Comment: your entity mapping is completely opposite to your table structure, based on your table structure `@OneToOne` should be on the opposite side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity and table structure looks opposite, and that making so much confusion to understand.

Now, referring to exception

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TableName.TEST_ID) violated - parent key not found
```

This mean, you don't have reference of parent id in child table when adding new row to child table.

In `Ew_test_reftable` class, you have

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "TESTID")
private int testid;
```

If I understand correctly, `testid` is your foreign key in `EW_TEST_REFTABLE`, then why are you using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` ? This will create new sequence id and may not match with parent key and result in error/exception.

As per my understanding of your design,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "TESTID")
private int testid;
```

change to

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "TESTID",unique = true)
private Ew_testdata ew_testdata;
```

And similar to above code should be removed from `Ew_testdata` entity (There might be slight change here and there)

Comment: Thanks Sir,It worked for me.Thanks your for your help

Comment: @brk Glad to help you, and don't call me sir :P